# Como posso por um botão a tornar visível?

Tags: java, android, button, visibilidade

Como posso clicar num botão e fazer o outro botão visível??

```
Button vibrar;

 cor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cores);

 public void clica (View View){
    cor.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: Em qual linguagem? `C#` `Java` ???

Comment: A linguagem é Java.

Comment: Tem que criar um `OnClickListener` para receber o click do button, atráves do método `SetOnClickListener`.

Comment: Vc inseriu o `onclick` no botão vibrar no arquivo xml, correto? Mas vc está setando o id, como vc fez no botão cores ? `vibrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.vibrar);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que falta a você é ter um *listener* no botão `vibrar` e neste *listener* fazer a troca de visibilidade do botão `cor`. Por exemplo:

```
Button vibrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.vibrar);
Button cor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cores);

vibrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        cor.setVisibity(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score -1):

Acho que isso resolve.

```
Button bt1 = findViewById(R.id.bt1);
Button bt2 = findViewById(R.id.bt2);

bt1.setOnclickListerner(new ... {
   bt2.setVisibility("gone");
});
```

Só é a base, tem que arrumar... Não quer tudo na mão né.